# Cursor image to the center on mouseout

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm a real noobie with flash and I was wondering if somebody could help me with this one.

I have this actionsript 3 code, where the cursor image "ball_mc" follows the mouse's position with a slight delay:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followBall);

function followBall(event:Event):void {
var dx:int = ball_mc.x - mouseX;
var dy:int = ball_mc.y - mouseY;
ball_mc.x -= dx / 5;
ball_mc.y -= dy /5;
}
```

1) How can I get the cursor image automatically return to the center of the stage on mouseout? As of now, it stays at the position where the mouse leaves the stage.

2) How can I reverse the movement of the mouse? So that when I, for example, move mouse to the right, the cursor image would move to the left? And when moving the mouse up, the image would go down.

The stage is 800 x 250 pixels, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

for first you can do it like this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, comeTOCenter);
function comeToCenter(e:MouseEvent):void {
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followBall);
ball_mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
ball_mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, followBall);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, cursorOut);

function  followBall(evt:MouseEvent):void  {
 var dx:int = mouseX-stage.stageWidth;
 var dy:int = mouseY-stage.stageHeight;
 ball_mc.x = -dx ;
 ball_mc.y = -dy ;
} 

function cursorOut(evt:Event):void {
 ball_mc.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
 ball_mc.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
}
```

the cursorOut function and his EventListner are for the first problem, and the followBall for the second one.